# Correctly Converting Numbers to Colors in R (in Matrices or Otherwise)

Tags: r, matrix

I'm in the process of converting number matrices to color matrices; however, the colors aren't displaying correctly, e.g., the color matrix displays the incorrect color relative to the assigned number in the number matrix.

I first assigned colors to a set of numerical values.

```
cols <- c(
'0' = "#FFFFFF",
'1' = "#9AFC7F",
'2' = "#77F255",
'3' = "#60DF3D",
'4' = "#49C925",
'5' = "#37B215",
'6' = "#219900"
)
```

Then generated a couple matrices.

```
Map1 <- read.table(text="
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   2   1
1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2   1
0   1   1   0   2   2   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2
1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   2
1   2   0   1   1   2   1   2   1   2
0   2   2   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   0   1   2   2   1   0
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
")

Map2 <- read.table(text="
1   2   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   2   2   1   2   2   3   2
0   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   2   2
1   1   0   2   1   1   3   2   3   3
1   1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2
0   1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2
1   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
")
```

After plotting the matrices, I find the colors don't match up with the value they should have been assigned.

```
image(1:nrow(Map1), 1:ncol(Map1), t(apply(Map1, 2, rev)), col=cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)

image(1:nrow(Map2), 1:ncol(Map2), t(apply(Map2, 2, rev)), col=cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
```

[image: Map 1]

[image: Map 2]

I've been stumped trying to figure out why the numbers and colors aren't aligning. Plotting the numbers assigned in to `cols` generates the correct sequence.

```
d <- read.table(text="0 1 2 3 4 5 6")
image(1:nrow(d), 1:ncol(d), t(apply(d, 2, rev)), col=cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
```

[image: Color Sequence]

There aren't any `6` values in the first number matrix, so there shouldn't be any dark squares in the first color matrix. It appears as though values of `2` are given the color assigned to `6` in the first matrix, and `3` to `6` in the second.

Adding a `3` into the first number matrix seems to shift the other values down the color scale, i.e., the largest number in the matrix is assigned the darkest color, rather than the color it was assigned in `cols`.

```
Map1.2 <- read.table(text="
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   2   1
1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2   1
3   1   1   0   2   2   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2
1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   2
1   2   0   1   1   2   1   2   1   2
0   2   2   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   0   1   2   2   1   0
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
")

image(1:nrow(Map1), 1:ncol(Map1), t(apply(Map1, 2, rev)), col=cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
image(1:nrow(Map1.2), 1:ncol(Map1.2), t(apply(Map1.2, 2, rev)), col=cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
```

[image: Map 1 containing a matrix of <code>0</code> <code>1</code> and <code>2</code>]

[image: Map 1 containing a matrix of <code>0</code> <code>1</code> <code>2</code> and <code>3</code>]

The only difference between the number matrices which generated these two color matrices is the `0` in the first column, third row was changed to a `3`.

Comment: Good question, but (1) can you please include data that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ? (2) you should be aware that code snippets don't do anything useful for R code - best to just use indentation for code blocks

Comment: All the data needed to reproduce the problem should be in the question. The only data are the number matrices, and the only code I used is on the page here.

Comment: The number matrices are not in a particularly convenient format for reproducing ... (also, would (much) smaller matrices be easier to work with for reproducing the problem?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, as you noted, is that the colours are being determined by the values in the matrix. This is because `image()` automatically spreads the values in the matrix across the range of colours provided. To spread them as you intended, you need to set the `zlim` argument to cover the length of your vector. Take a look at the help page (`?image`) for more details about this.

So, to correct your image, you can do the following:

```
cols <- c("#FFFFFF", "#9AFC7F", "#77F255", "#60DF3D", "#49C925", "#37B215", "#219900")

Map1 <- read.table(text="
  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   2   1
  1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2   1
  0   1   1   0   2   2   1   1   1   1
  0   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2
  1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2
  1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   2
  1   2   0   1   1   2   1   2   1   2
  0   2   2   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
  0   1   1   0   0   1   2   2   1   0
  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
")

image(1:ncol(Map1), 1:nrow(Map1), t(sapply(Map1, rev)),
  zlim = c(0, length(cols) - 1),  # This will spread you numbers properly
  col = cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
```

[image]

Here's another example:

```
cols <- c("#FFFFFF", "#9AFC7F", "#77F255", "#60DF3D", "#49C925", "#37B215", "#219900")
set.seed(123)
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0, 1, 5, 6), 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
image(1:ncol(d), 1:nrow(d), t(sapply(d, rev)), 
  zlim = c(0, length(cols) - 1),
  col = cols, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, bty='n', asp = 1)
```

[image]

Some side notes:

- The color vector (`cols`) does not require names. The order is sufficient.
- If you use data starting from 1 instead of 0, set to `zlim = c(1, length(cols))`.
- I shortened `apply(Map1, 2, rev)` with `sapply(Map1, rev)`.
- I swapped `1:ncol()` and `1:nrow()`, as the original order did not work with a rectangular table.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're having a problem with mapping of numbers to characters. If `x` is numeric then `cols[x]` will reference the vector by number, not by name ...

I changed the first colour to red (instead of white) to make the values a little more obvious.

```
cols <- c('0' = "#FF0000",'1' = "#9AFC7F",'2' = "#77F255",'3' = "#60DF3D",
    '4' = "#49C925",'5' = "#37B215",'6' = "#219900")
```

Check colour definitions:

```
plot(0:6,rep(1,7),col=cols,pch=16,cex=5,ylim=c(0.9,1.1),
     axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE,mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

[image]

```
m <- matrix(0:5,ncol=2)
image(m,col=cols[m])  ## index by number
```

[image]

Now index by name:

```
image(m,col=cols[as.character(m)])
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having difficulty successfully applying this solution to my problem; however, in my attempts--and after editing the original question to make it more reproducible and concise--I found the problem seems to be the color matrix is assigning the highest value in the number matrix to the darkest color, rather than the value in `cols`. I added details and new images to the bottom of the original question for clarity.

Comment: if you think you've resolved your own question, go ahead and post the solution as an answer (as soon as you're allowed to)

Comment: I haven't resolved the question; my addition to the original question is an error I hadn't noticed previously which may be valuable in solving the issue I'm having. I'm still unable to correct the problem.